# Why variable is undefined inside foreach function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery function were I create a table:

```
function propertyView(values) {

// build the table
var frame = '<fieldset id = "propertiesValueArea" style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">';
var content = frame + smallHeader + '<table data-role="table" id="propertiesList"><thead><tr></tr></thead>';

$.each($(values), function () {
    var data1 = this.RealValue.FieldValue;
    var data2 = this.RealValue.Id;
    //create tables row 
    content += '<tr data-id=' + this.Id + '>';
    content += '<td style="vertical-align: inherit;text-align:center;"><label for="">' + this.FieldName + '</label></td>';
    if (this.FieldValue.indexOf(',') > -1) {
        content += '<td style="text-align:center;"><select>';
        this.FieldValue.split(',').forEach(function (item) {

            if (data1 === item) //Here data1 is undefined!!!
            {
                content += '<option selected="selected" value="">' + item + '</option>';
            }
            else {
                content += '<option value="">' + item + '</option>';
            }
        })
        content += '</select></td>';
    }
    else {
        content += '<td style="text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="propFieldName" data-id="' + this.Id + '" value="' + congiValue(this.FieldValue, this.RealValue) + '"/>';
    }
    content += '</tr>';
});
content += '</table>';
content += '</fieldset>'

return content;
}
```

Inside outter each function I create 2 variables:
        var data1 = this.RealValue.FieldValue;
        var data2 = this.RealValue.Id;

I try to create this variable inside inner each:

```
 if (data1 === item) //Here data1 is undefined!!!
```

But on this row I get this error:

```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: data1 is not defined
```

Any idea why data1 is undefined?

Comment: Probably because of this.RealValue.FieldValue is undefined. You should check if (data1 != undefined && data1 === item)

Comment: What exactly is `values`?  Because `$.each()` is intended to be used with normal arrays, not a jQuery object such as `$(values)`.  If `values` contains DOM Elements, you should use the `$(values).each()` version.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the error?

Comment: What is the RealValue in JavaScript ?

Comment: Even if `data1` is undefined you should not see the error here, are you sure the error is on this line?

Comment: Like @MunimMunna has commented, even if **data1** have the **undefined** value, the sentence **(data1 === item)** will return **true** or **false** depending if the value of item is also **undefined** or not. The error you receive is because **data1** don't exists on the scope of that sentence. An example of **values** (the argument of the propertyView() mehod) will help to trace the real problem.

Comment: You have not posted complete code, there are things not defined, `smallHeader`, `this.RealValue`, `this.FieldValue`, and `congiValue()`

Comment: Can you also add the code around the actual call site of yor `propertyView(...)` function ? What is the definition of `RealValue` for each item of `$(values)` ?

Answer (score 2):

It can be `undefined` only because `this.RealValue.FieldValue` or `this.RealValue` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
var data1 = this.RealValue.FieldValue; //it's value is undefined
this.FieldValue  //it's value is undefined
```

try to

```
console.log(this.FieldValue)
console.log(data1)
```

After that you can easily found where you are getting an error and why. Else everything looks fine with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem before. It took me several hours to discover the problem. Now that aside there some things which is not clear here.

1. is the value coming from another function's operation? If

   ```
   this.RealValue.FieldValue;
   ```

   is coming from e.g. a result of maybe another function then you would need to use async/await to ensure that the function completes its operation and there is data in **this.RealValue.FieldValue** before you move on to the next line of code.
2. Maybe the **this.RealValue.FieldValue** itself does not have any thing assigned to it outside of the function itself.

In order to help you we would need a complete code. If you think your code is too private then you can go through it by trying what @Negi Rox said earlier.

Put console.log(this.RealValue.FieldValue) at various strategic locations in your code to determine when it was assigned a value.